# form_set_error not showing error message on webform

Tags: forms, webforms

I have created my own module and when i try to use form_set_error all im getting is the red border around the form input but no error message.

here is my code

```
function dd_alert_register_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)
{
    if($form_id === 'webform_client_form_123'){
        $form['#validate'][]='dd_alert_register_form_validate';     
    }
}

function dd_alert_register_form_validate($form,&$form_state)
{
    //where "phone" is field name of webform phone field
    $email = $form_state['values']['submitted']['email_address'];

    if ((bool) db_select('users')->fields('users', array('uid'))->condition('mail', db_like($email), 'LIKE')->range(0, 1)->execute()->fetchField()) {
        form_set_error('submitted][email_address',t('The e-mail address is already registered'));
        return $form;
    }
    // Then use regular expression to validate it.
    // In above example i have check if phonefield is empty or not.
}
```

Comment: Presumably you're calling `drupal_get_form()` in a template file - you shouldn't do that

Comment: No, i have not added any code in my template file.

Comment: Basically what's happening is that the messages are being added to the session _after_ theyve already been displayed for the current page (after page.tpl.php is processed). If you continue browsing after the form submission you should see the messages on the next page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it could also happen if `$messages` haven't printed in the `page.tpl.php` in your theme.

Is the `<?php print $messages; ?>` included in your `page.tpl.php` file?

Check this line in your page template. You might have missed it.

Hope it will help you!